# How to make the drop down list in header frame overlap body frame?

Tags: css, header, positioning, frame

I have a header frame, and a body content frame.

My header frame by default is to put logo and logout button.

My body frame is to put all the contents.

Issue now is:

I decided to add in a drop down menu at header frame. 
When scroll over, it will drop down a long list.

But, when scroll over, it drop down inside the header frame itself. I want it to drop down menu to overlapping the body frame.

I know it can easily done if all the thing is in 1 single page.

But now I'm using frame.

Is there any way to work out on this? CSS? or ? or no way at all?

Comment: It would be better if you div's and not frames....is there any reason that you have chosen frames?

Comment: I want to do this too, the reason I choose frame is because I don't want the menu (which can be big) to get reloaded every time the the content frame refreshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. Each frame is a separate page. One more case for not using frames.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both of the pages exist on the same site, you can use Javascript to control one frame from the other.

Put the menu in the top frame, and the flyout part with a height of 0 in the lower frame.

Then add a mouseover event to the top menu which calls a function in the other frame to expand the flyout part.

Basically, it *could* be done. But I have no idea why you would it that way.
  It would be brittle [not always work - what if JS is off], hard to setup, and limited in capability.

If you just like getting frustrated, you needn't worry, just spend more time getting things to work on IE6 :)